# Help creating apex class and schedulable apex class that will update all my custom object on a daily basis

Tags: apex, custom-object, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job, chargent

I have a custom object 'chargent order', and a field 'todays date'. The classes save and they schedule and run, but nothing updates, and I can't figure out why.

---

```
global class ChargentDailyUpdate {
    global static void checkUpdate(ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c[] objects){
        for(ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c  obj: objects){
            obj.Todays_Date__c= date.today();
        }
    }
}



global class ChargentSchedulable implements Schedulable {
   global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
      ChargentDailyUpdate CDU = new ChargentDailyUpdate(); 
   }
}
```

---

I also would appreciate any advice on whether there are better ways to do this, and if this is the way should I do a batch job like 20 at a time (there are about 1000 records and workflows that fire off the 'todays date' changing). I think this method does all 1000 at the same time but I'm not certain, I don't have much apex experience. Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you didn't actually call the method you needed to call. More to the point, you probably wanted a batchable class in case there's too many records to process.

```
global class ChargentSchedulable implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<SObject> {
   global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
      Database.executeBatch(this);
   }
   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
     return Database.getQueryLocator(
       [SELECT Id FROM ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c]
     );
   }
   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c[] scope) {
     for(ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c record: scope) {
       record.Todays_Date__c = Date.today();
     }
     update scope;
  }
  global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
  // Required, but nothing to do
  }
}
```

Comment: you missed the update statement in execute method. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You also forgot to implement the `Batchable` interface.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Ah hahaha. Not my finest moment, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are missing the update statement.

Try below code:

```
global class ChargentDailyUpdate {
    global static void checkUpdate(ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c[] objects){
        for(ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c  obj: objects){
            obj.Todays_Date__c= date.today();
        }
       Update objects;
    }
}
```

---

```
global class ChargentSchedulable implements Schedulable {
   global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
      List<ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c> objects = [SELECT Id FROM ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c]; // update any conditions if you have in where clause
if(!objects.isEmpty())      
ChargentDailyUpdate.checkUpdate(objects); // static method call
   } 
}
```

Comment: Your `Schedulable` implementation doesn't ever call `checkUpdate`...

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks Larson. I have updated the code